# Extract certificate information using openssl

Tags: openssl, cms

I would like to verify the sender and 'addressee' certificate information of an encrypted/signed file. So far, I came up with the following set of arguments to openssl:

```
openssl cms -inform DER -cmsout -print -recip my.crt -in cms_file
```

This returns the following information:

```
CMS_ContentInfo: 
  contentType: pkcs7-envelopedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.3)
  d.envelopedData: 
    version: 2
    originatorInfo:
...
            issuer: O=TheirCompany, CN=TheirCA
...
            subject: O=TheirCompany, CN=TheirEndpoint
...
    recipientInfos:
...
          issuer: O=TheirCompany, CN=TheirCA
...
```

So I've got most of the information I'm looking for, except the subject of the recipient. How do I extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you *can* do this, since the `recipientInfos` structure is not defined, *e.g.* per [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652), to contain a *certificate*.  Keys, yes...but not certificates.

RFC 5652, Section 6.1 "EnvelopedData Type" specifies the structure of `OriginatorInfo`, which *may* contain a set of certificates.  Section 6.2 "ReicipientInfo Type" and subsections describe the structure of the possible `RecipientInfo` types; none of those types' structures contain certificates.  Thus it may not be possible, given the current structures, to achieve what you are looking for.